# How to import a Python's regular package into Sage?

Tags: python-3.x, package, sage

I'm writing Sage scripts with the aid of the Jupyter notebook. It's all fine until I try to import regular Python packages/libraries, things I installed with `pip` or otherwise and sit under `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/`. Say, CoolProp, a fluid property package. When I try:

```
import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b88e3e84ef2b> in <module>
----> 1 import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CoolProp'
```

I assume I should provide the path to CoolProp somehow, but how to do this within a script? I have Sage installed under ~/sage-9.3.

Answer (score 5):

#### Installing Python packages for Sage

The packages should be installed for Sage's Python,
which, depending on how you installed Sage, might
not be your system Python.

If `sage` is in your PATH, try this in a terminal:

```
sage --pip install CoolProp
```

Otherwise, use the full path:

```
~/sage-9.3/sage --pip install CoolProp
```

Alternatively, at the Sage prompt (or in
a Jupyter notebook running the Sage kernel), run:

```
%pip install CoolProp
```

After that, the import should work.

#### Duplicate copies of packages

One way to avoid keeping duplicate copies of packages is to always use Sage's Python.

It can be started by running `sage --python` or `~/sage-9.3/local/bin/python`.

Other possibilities include using an alias:

```sh
alias python='sage --python'
```

or

```sh
alias python='~/sage-9.3/local/bin/python'
```

or tweaking your `PATH` shell variable:

```sh
PATH=~/sage-9.3/local/bin:$PATH
```

The line defining the alias or setting the PATH
could be added to your shell settings file
(which could be `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`
or `.zshrc` or similar).

Better, add a symlink to Sage's Python to some location
that is earlier in your `PATH` than your system Python:

```sh
ln -s ~/sage-9.3/local/bin:$PATH /usr/local/bin
```

or, if that gives a permission error,

```sh
sudo ln -s ~/sage-9.3/local/bin:$PATH /usr/local/bin
```

The advantage is this command can be run once and for all,
with no need to change your shell settings file.

In all cases, running `python` will run Sage's Python.

To stop using Sage's Python as your main Python,
either delete the line defining an alias or
tweaking your PATH from your shell settings file,
or remove the symlink if you used that solution:

```sh
rm /usr/local/bin/python
```

or, if that gives a permission error,

```sh
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python
```

#### Dedicated environments

One modern trend is to use dedicated environments
for each project you work on, with a description
of that environment stored in a text file.

This can be done with Python's venv or with Conda.

Comment: This means I should keep duplicate copies of every package I use in both Python and Sage, eh?

Comment: @FaustoArinosBarbuto -- I expanded my answer to address that point.

Comment: The magic command `%pip install ...`  in the sage command prompt, at least in ipython-like environment (not tested in jupyter) worked for me, at least on a different package (Bliss).